# C# ASP.NET SQL Parameterize

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I have seen some examples how to use parameters to avoid character escaping. Does using parameters is 100% safe against SQL injection?

Also, can you please give some basic queries (which are reguraly used), and how you implement the parameters?

Some websites I searched before I came here provided too complicated examples.

Comment: I hesitate to state that anything is 100% safe. Also, what do you mean by regularly used queries? It's entirely dependent on your data model.

Answer (score 2):

A basic example of a parameterized SQL query is as follows:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"select city from users where username = @username", conn);
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@username";
param.Value = "abc123"
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

`conn` is the SqlConnection that you've established.

`@username` is the parameter name that will be substituted when the command is executed.

`abc123` is the made up username that I've put for the example.

This is obviously a made up scenario, but you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

As a shorter version you can use

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"select city from users where username = @username", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "value");
```

Comment: OK - but using the `.AddWithValue()` method basically tells ADO.NET to guess the data type used - which it does quite well, most of the time. But sometimes, it's off - quite a bit off, at times. Therefore, I would not recommend this - it's always better to **explicitly define** the data type and not leave this up to guesswork by the ADO.NET runtime.....

Comment: I believe there is an overload for `AddWithValue` that lets you pass a type.